# Brake Bleed Sequence for Chevrolet Suburban 2015

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, suburban, bleeding

I'm trying to locate the correct sequence for brake bleeding my 2015 Chevrolet Suburban 1500 LTZ 4wd with stabilitrak. I did farthest to closest from master calendar.

The front seem to bleed fast (shooting out), but not the rear. I replaced all lines with steel braided brake lines, including the stabilitrak lines going to the rear axle.

Is there another bleeder I'm missing or did I bleed incorrectly? Could the hoses on the axle still have air in?

Answer (score 0):

It can take some time. Your doing it correctly, farest to nearest. You will most likely need to perform the sequence a few times. Make sure the m/c doesn't run out of fluid. I find it better to pump the brakes slowly then crack the bleeder open. You'll need some help with this. Once bleeder is cracked open DO NOT RELEASE the brake pedal. It'll suck air back into the lines.  Hope this helps

Comment: We did that exactly, twice in fact. I've learned that it might have something to do with the ABS pulse and it may need to be connected to a specific tool that Chevrolet has. Are there any GM mechanics on here who might know?

Comment: You could if you have easy enough access to the abs unit. Try and bleed the lines from the master cylinder to the abs unit. Once bled work you way back to the wheels as before. Or get a pressure bleeder.  Good luck

Comment: Did you bleed it with the engine off and then running? Did you bleed it with a hose inside brake fluid?

Comment: I only bled it with the engine running. I ended up taking it into GM and having them do with their machine.